# How to install a non-distro package inside Docker without wasting space?

Tags: docker

In Docker, you can install packages in the normal way for your distro, e.g. `apt-get install xyz` for Debian.  This results in only one copy of the package appearing in the container (the installed copy.)

Instead, if you have a package you have built that is not part of your distro's repositories (e.g. a standalone `.deb`, `.rpm` or other package), how can you install this in the Docker container such that the package file itself doesn't remain in the container after the install?

For example, if you do something like this:

```
ADD example.deb /home
RUN dpkg -i /home/example.deb && rm /home/example.deb
```

Then because `ADD` and `RUN` are separate commands, you end up with your final container having both the installed package *and* the original `.deb` file as well.  This means a 100MB package will inflate the container by 200+MB, because you end up with two copies of the package - the installed content plus the original file.

Mounting a volume during the build process would solve the problem nicely, but apparently this is against the Docker philosophy.  I would like to avoid running extra services if possible, so serving the packages so the distro's normal package manager can find them or even running a web server so the container can `wget` the file is something I'd like to avoid if any of it has to happen outside the container itself.

Comment: you can purge package manager cache according to his documented procedure, btw it's a wide practice for Dockerfile's

Comment: that won't help in this case, the layer will already be written.

Comment: you could put the .deb somewhere online and wget or curl it in the same RUN command as dpkg and rm. this question actually belongs more on the [superuser](https://superuser.com/) site